# What is the best way to check for empty request Body?

Tags: http, go

From the [documentation](https://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go) it states that

> For server requests the Request Body is always non-nil but will return EOF immediately when no body is present.

For ContentLength, the documentation states

> For client requests, a value of 0 means **unknown** if Body is not nil.

So is it better to check for ContentLength

```
r *http.Request
if r.ContentLength == 0 {
  //empty body
}
```

or to check EOF

```
type Input struct {
    Name *string `json:"name"`
}

input := new(Input)

if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(input); err.Error() == "EOF" {
 //empty body
}
```

Comment: Clearly EOF, `Content-Length` is a header that the client can or cannot set.

Comment: Don't muck with the string value of errors. If you're looking for `io.EOF` then do `if err == io.EOF`. Looking at the string representation is at best incredibly fragile.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You always need to read the body to know what the contents are. The client could send the body in chunked encoding with no `Content-Length`, or it could even have an error and send a `Content-Length` and no body. The client is never obligated to send what it says it's going to send.

The `EOF` check can work if you're only checking for the empty body, but I would still also check for other error cases besides the `EOF` string.

```
err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(input)
switch {
case err == io.EOF:
    // empty body
case err != nil:
    // other error
}
```

You can also read the entire body before unmarshalling:

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
```

or if you're worried about too much data

```
body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(io.LimitReader(r.Body, readLimit))
```

Answer (score 23):

```
if http.Request().Body == http.NoBody {
  // TODO.
}
```

Comment: That method does not exist in `http`, we can access the `Body` field from the `Request` type: https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Request instead